# Select query with left outer join and sum with group by

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, left-join

I have 3 tables for example

**Parent Table :TEST_SUMMARY**

**Child Tables : TEST_DETAIL, TEST_DETAIL2**

[image: Image Attached]

I have data show in image, and want output result shown in image,

I tried below 2 query, but not giving expected output

```
SELECT s.NAME, sum(s.AMT), sum(d.d_amt), sum(d2.d2_amt)
FROM TEST_SUMMARY s LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST_DETAIL d
ON s.ID = d.SUMMARY_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST_DETAIL2 d2
ON s.ID =d2.SUMMARY_ID
GROUP BY s.NAME
ORDER BY s.NAME;

select rs1.*,rs2.total1,rs3.total2
FROM
(select id, name,amt from TEST_SUMMARY a) RS1,
(select SUMMARY_ID, sum(d_amt) over(partition by summary_id ) total1 from TEST_DETAIL a) RS2,
(select SUMMARY_ID, sum(d2_amt) over(partition by summary_id ) total2 from TEST_DETAIL2 a) RS3
where rs1.id(+)= RS2.SUMMARY_ID
and rs1.id(+)= RS3.SUMMARY_ID;
```

Create table and insert data test Queries

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_SUMMARY(ID NUMBER, NAME VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),AMT  NUMBER(10,2));

CREATE TABLE TEST_DETAIL (ID NUMBER, SUMMARY_ID NUMBER, NAME VARCHAR(20), D_AMT NUMBER(10,2));

CREATE TABLE TEST_DETAIL2 (ID NUMBER, SUMMARY_ID NUMBER, NAME VARCHAR(20), D2_AMT NUMBER(10,2));

INSERT INTO TEST_SUMMARY VALUES (1, 'NAME1', 100);
INSERT INTO TEST_SUMMARY VALUES (4, 'NAME1', 150);
INSERT INTO TEST_SUMMARY VALUES (6, 'NAME1', 50);
INSERT INTO TEST_SUMMARY VALUES (2, 'NAME2', 200);
INSERT INTO TEST_SUMMARY VALUES (3, 'NAME3', 300);

INSERT INTO TEST_DETAIL VALUES (1, 1, 'NAME11', 11);
INSERT INTO TEST_DETAIL VALUES (2, 1, 'NAME12', 12);

INSERT INTO TEST_DETAIL2 VALUES (1, 1, 'NAME_2_11', 1);
INSERT INTO TEST_DETAIL2 VALUES (2, 1, 'NAME_2_12', 1);
```

Comment: Is this MySQL or Oracle? Cannot be both.

Comment: It should work for both.

Comment: @shree.pat18 It's Oracle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to solve it for both MySQL and Oracle is to use subqueries to help solve the duplication for you by aggregating the sums from the details tables by name, so you can summarise with a normal join;

```
SELECT ts.name, SUM(ts.amt) amt1, MAX(td1.amt) amt2, MAX(td2.amt) amt3
FROM TEST_SUMMARY ts
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ts.name, SUM(td.d_amt) amt 
  FROM TEST_DETAIL td JOIN TEST_SUMMARY ts ON td.summary_id = ts.id
  GROUP BY ts.name) td1 ON ts.name = td1.name
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ts.name, SUM(td.d2_amt) amt 
  FROM TEST_DETAIL2 td JOIN TEST_SUMMARY ts ON td.summary_id = ts.id
  GROUP BY ts.name) td2 ON ts.name = td2.name
GROUP BY ts.name
ORDER BY ts.name
```

[A MySQL SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0834/1) and [an Oracle SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cdd49/2) to test with.

Comment: Yes, It's giving expected result. Thanks !!!. Any idea or suggestion on how to achieve the same for MYSQL database.

Comment: @RahulAgrawal Updated with a query that works on both MySQL and Oracle.

Comment: Thanks !!, hope this will not have performance penalty, as in detail tables we may have approx 2 million records

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
SELECT
    TEST_SUMMARY.NAME,
    TEST_SUMMARY.AMT AS AMT1,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(TEST_DETAIL.D_AMT)
        FROM
            TEST_DETAIL
        WHERE
            TEST_DETAIL.SUMMARY_ID=TEST_SUMMARY.ID
    ) AS AMT2,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(TEST_DETAIL2.D2_AMT)
        FROM
            TEST_DETAIL2
        WHERE
            TEST_DETAIL2.SUMMARY_ID=TEST_SUMMARY.ID
    ) AS AMT3
FROM
    TEST_SUMMARY
```

**Update**

You could basically do this if you have many name that are the same. But the question comes what you should do with the other fields (AMT1,AMT2)? Should you sum them for the same name or maybe a max is enough. Depends on what your requirement are :

```
SELECT
    TEST_SUMMARY.NAME,
    SUM(TEST_SUMMARY.AMT) AS AMT,
    SUM(tblAMT2.AMT2) AS AMT2,
    SUM(tblAMT3.AMT3) AS AMT3
FROM
    TEST_SUMMARY
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(TEST_DETAIL.D_AMT) AS AMT2,
            TEST_DETAIL.SUMMARY_ID
        FROM
            TEST_DETAIL
        GROUP BY
            TEST_DETAIL.SUMMARY_ID
    ) AS tblAMT2
        ON TEST_SUMMARY.ID=tblAMT2.SUMMARY_ID
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(TEST_DETAIL2.D2_AMT) AS AMT3,
            TEST_DETAIL2.SUMMARY_ID
        FROM
            TEST_DETAIL2
        GROUP BY
            TEST_DETAIL2.SUMMARY_ID
    ) AS tblAMT3
        ON TEST_SUMMARY.ID=tblAMT3.SUMMARY_ID
GROUP BY
    TEST_SUMMARY.NAME
```

Comment: This looks ok, only problem with this query is sum(TEST_SUMMARY.AMT), can you suggest something for that.

Comment: The data that you have provided shows that it is not need. Have you tested it? Or do you have more data that you have not provided in your question?

Comment: It's sample tables and test data, I have provided in question, actual domain tables I can't provide due to some policy. But actual data has multiple amt's for same name in SUMMARY table. So sum is required.

Comment: @RahulAgrawal : The link that you provided. Is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  SELECT TS.NAME, TS.AMT AS AMT1, SUM(TD.D_AMT) AS AMT2, SUM(TD2.D2_AMT) AS AMT3
    FROM TEST_SUMMARY TS LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST_DETAIL TD   ON TS.ID = TD.SUMMARY_ID
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST_DETAIL2 TD2 ON TS.ID = TD2.SUMMARY_ID
GROUP BY TS.NAME, TS.AMT
ORDER BY TS.NAME, TS.AMT
```

Comment: This is not giving expected result, as left out join in required with summary table, from summary table all records should come always.

Comment: did you executed my query?

Comment: This looks correct @Rahul. Ahmet, could you please explain _why_ this answers the question?

Comment: Because, @RahulAgrawal 's query SUM the TEST_SUMMARY.AMT field. I think, this causes the wrong result.

Comment: Yes, but I want to sum(TEST_SUMMARY.AMT) as TEST_SUMMARY can have multiple amt for same name. updated query does not give correct result. I have executed it.